# Арифметическое действие в переменной

Tags: python

Нужно сделать так чтобы функция принимала 3 значения

1, 2 - числа

3 значение - символ арифм. действия

Думал через перегрузку оператора, но так и не придумал как это сделать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def f(op, a, b):
    ...

f('+', 1, 2)
```